# Controller looks not applied in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, module, controller

I'm starting learning angular js.
So i'm making very simple module and controller class. But it is not working.
Here is my sample code.
Can  u point out what's wrong?

```
            <html ng-app="demoApp">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

                var controllers = {};

                <!-- create controller class -->
                function SimpleController($scope){
                    $scope.customers = [
                            {name:'Terry.Cho',city:'Seoul'},
                            {name:'Cath',city:'Suwon'},
                            {name:'Carry',city:'Suwon'}
                    ];
                }

                <!-- add the controller to controller array -->
                controllers.SimpleController = SimpleController;
                <!-- pass the controllers array to module -->
                demoApp.controller(controllers);

                </script>
            </head>
            <body>

                        <h3> Controller example </h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:'name' ">{{cust.name}}</li>
                    </ul>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add ng-controller="SimpleController" to either your body tag or your ul tag. Add that and you should be good.

Comment: Thanx. Zack. In the example http://www.angularjs.org/new here. "Wire up a Backend". It seems like it doesn't define ng-controller. In my understanding without defining controller by using "ng-controller" it seems like automatically assigned to the module and view. Am i wrong?

Comment: That is because the controller is defined in the $routeProvider for each template. Since you aren't using $routeProvider, you have to define the controller in the html. You can see an example in "Add Some Control" right above "Wire up a Backend".